# What should be approach to store publicly writable data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `user-profile` collection. Currently it is writable by only the user whose profile it is.

Now I want to record the count 'no of times the profile visited' let say `profileVisitedCount`. And, it also counts if a non-signedIn user visit the profile.

If I store the count in the documents of `user-profile` collection itself from firebase js client library, I will have to make it publicly writable.

Other option I am thinking is to have a cloud function. It will only increment the `profileVisitedCount` without need of making the the document publicly writable. But not sure if it is a correct approach, as the cloud function endpoint seems still vulnerable and can be called by bot.

Also, yes 'the profile visit count' kind of data should be recorded in analytics like GA but I need this count to use in one of the business logic like displaying top visited profiles.

So, any guidance on how the data should be structured? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could have another collection called, for example, `profileVisitsCounters` in which you store one document per user with a document Id corresponding to the user Id. In this user document, you maintain a dedicated `profileVisitedCount` field that you update with [`increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) each time a user reads the corresponding profile.

You assign full read and write access to this collection with `allow read, write: if true;`.

---

In your question, while mentioning the Cloud Function solution, you write that "the cloud function endpoint seems still vulnerable and can be called by bot". Be aware that in the case of an extra collection with full write access, as detailed above, it will also be the case: for example, someone who knows the collection name and user uid(s) could call the `update()` method of the JavaScript SDK or, even easier, an endpoint of the [Cloud Firestore API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch).

---

If you want to avoid this risk you could use a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to read the User Profiles, as you have mentioned. This Cloud Function will:

1. Fetch the User Profile data;
2. Increment the `profileVisitedCount` field (in the User Profile document);
3. Send back the User Profile data to the client.

You need to deny read access right to the `user-profile` collection, in order to force the users to "read" it through the Cloud Function.

This way you are sure that the `profileVisitedCount` fields **are only incremented when there is a "real" User Profile read**.

Note also that you could still keep the `profileVisitsCounters` collection if having two different collections brings some extra advantages for your business case. In this case, the Cloud Function would increment the counter in this collection, instead of incrementing it in the User Profile itself. You would restrict the access right of the `profileVisitsCounters` collection to read only since the Cloud Function bypasses the security rules. (`allow read: if true; allow write: if false;`).

---

Finally, note that it might be interesting to read this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c), which, among others, details the pros and cons of querying Firebase databases with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank @Renaud Tarnec, thank for detailed explanation and options. 

If I go with _callable Cloud Function_ to read user profile, won't it be again publicly exposed and can be called by bot scripts?